# How to optimize sql of left join?

Tags: mysql, left-join

I have two table **phone** and **phone_area**

**phone** columns:

> 1. id: pk
> 2. phone: unique index

**phone** data:

```
|id| phone       |
+--+-------------+
|1 | 1882601xxxx |
+--+-------------+
|2 | 1882602xxxx |
+--+-------------+
|2 | 1882602xxxx |
+--+-------------+
|2 | 1882603xxxx  | 
+--+-------------+
```

**phone_area** columns:

> 1.id: pk
>
> 2.phone: unique index
>
> 3.area: varchar(20)

**phone_area** data:

```
|id| phone  |  area    |  
+--+--------+----------+
|1 | 1882601|  area_one|
+--+--------+----------+
|2 | 1882602|  area_two|
+--+--------+----------+ 
|2 | 1882603|area_three|
+--+--------+----------+
```

My sql following:

```
SELECT t1.phone,t2.area FROM phone t1
LEFT JOIN phone_area t2 ON substr(t1.phone, 1, 7)= t2.phone
```

It is very slowly.

When explain the sql， it shows the **type** as "ALL" and **Using where; Using join buffer (Block Nested Loop)**

How to improve my sql?

Comment: You may give a try to this: `Create another column in phone table which will hold the same value as phone column. Then create a partial index on that newly created field. Later make a left join between this newly created field and the phone code in phone_area table`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follow this steps:

```
ALTER TABLE phone ADD phone_cut int; --add a new column

UPDATE phone SET phone_cut = substr(phone, 1, 7); --store the cropped value of phone

ALTER TABLE phone ADD INDEX ind_name (phone_cut); -- add an index on that column
```

And then :

```
SELECT t1.phone,t2.area FROM phone t1
LEFT JOIN phone_area t2
 ON t1.phone_cut= t2.phone
```

Comment: I would call the column `phone_prefix`, but the concept is good

Comment: Thanks, but it  exists some errors, the **phone_cut** should change type as int(same as **phone**).

Comment: Fixed @HeadwindFly , didn't see the definition